# How to develop with rsocket

Tags: c++, networking, linker, infiniband, rdma

I'm trying to use RDMA over infiniband as part of an application. I've discovered rsocket which looks like a useful API for RDMA. However I'm trying to use it but I have no idea what library I'm supposed to link with. I have rdma/rsocket.h included just fine.

I am quite a C++ noob, but my understanding is I need to link a library in too with -l but no idea what library is even used by rsocket.

```
#include <rdma/rsocket.h>
#include <rdma/rdma_cma.h>
#include <netdb.h>

...

struct addrinfo hints, *res;
int ret;
memset( &hints, 0, sizeof( hints ) );
hints.ai_flags = RAI_PASSIVE;
ret = getaddrinfo( "0.0.0.0", "7471", &hints, &res );
listening_socket = rsocket( res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol );
```

Results in

```
undefined reference to `rsocket'
```